# this macro replacement multiple times should give error?

Tags: c++, c, macros

```
#define a b
#define b c
#define c d
main()
{
    int a=192;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    printf("%d\n",c);
    printf("%d\n",d);
}
```

output is 192 for all. How a,b,c are declared?

Comment: Why do you think this should give an error?

Comment: Prior to any compilation int a=192 will be replaced by int d=192 i suppose ...

Comment: Yea, and all the output lines will look like `printf("%d\n",d);`

Comment: and all the lines will read `printf("%d\n",d);` (replace a,b,c by d) and thus everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

when you use a macro, you are telling the pre processor to replace the identifier (in your case, a, b, c) with the expression following the macro.

So that series of defines, tells the preprocessor to replace the contents of a with b, replace the contents of b with c, and replace the contents of c with d.

so what you get, is the same value being printed for times

```
main()
{
    int d = 192;
    printf("%d\n", d);
    printf("%d\n", d);
    printf("%d\n", d);
    printf("%d\n", d);
}
```

Comment: Actually the pre-processor doesn't care about variables.

Comment: That's right @Tomalak, thanks for catching that jargon mixup - they're actually called identifiers. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The resulting code is

```
main()
{
    int d=192;
    printf("%d\n",d);
    printf("%d\n",d);
    printf("%d\n",d);
    printf("%d\n",d);
}
```

which will of course print the same value four times.

Comment: yeah it was a sily q. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

In your defines you are saying to the compiler to substitute a->b, b->c, c->d in the end you are substituting everything with d

So your result code (after the preprocessor) is:

```
main()
{
    int d=192;
    printf("%d\n",d);
    printf("%d\n",d);
    printf("%d\n",d);
    printf("%d\n",d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the output of the preprocessor?

Hint:  What do you think the line

```
int a=192;
```

looks like after the preprocessing stage?